# Converting a Pandoc LaTeX template to a Documentclass

Tags: templates, document-classes, pandoc, documentclass-writing

This may be an inappropriate question to ask in a dedicated TeX/LaTeX forum, but I'm not sure where else to post it.

Are there any guidelines (or tools) for converting a Pandoc LaTeX template into a proper LaTeX documentclass? Specifically, I'd like to use the eisvogel template found here: [template GitHub link](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) directly in LaTeX as opposed to indirectly via Pandoc.